# Start: applet not initialized error in eclipse

Tags: java, applet

Class file not found error when trying to run the applet

```java
    package chapter1;

    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class CircleInSquare extends JApplet
    {
        public void paint(Graphics graphics)
        {
            final int X = 50, Y = 50, SIZE = 50;

            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            graphics.fillRect(X, Y, SIZE, SIZE);
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.fillOval(X, Y, SIZE, SIZE);
        }
    }
```

I've tried running the appletviewer from the command line and get the same results

Comment: It is 2019, applets are dead. **Really** dead. Exactly how are you running the appletviewer?

Comment: Applets are obsolete and most browsers no longer support them.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working out of book that uses version 5.  What has replaced applets?

Comment: Read [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates) and [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf).

Comment: Learn about [JavaFX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) and [Swing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)).